# Calico IPs Confusion

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I am bit confused about Calico IPs :

If I add calico to kubernetes cluster using

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.14/manifests/calico.yaml
```

The CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR is 192.168.0.0/16
So IP Range is 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255

Now I have initiated the cluster using :

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=20.96.0.0/12 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.30
```

So, now pods will have IP address (using pod network CIDR) will be between: 20.96.0.0 to 20.111.255.255

What are these two different IPs. My Pods are getting IP addresses 20.96.205.192 and so on.

Answer (score 8):

- The `CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR` is `#commented` by default, look at these lines in [calico.yaml](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.14/manifests/calico.yaml):

```
# The default IPv4 pool to create on startup if none exists. Pod IPs will be
# chosen from this range. Changing this value after installation will have
# no effect. This should fall within `--cluster-cidr`.
# - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR
#   value: "192.168.0.0/16"
```

**For all effects**, unless manually modified before deployment, **those lines are not considered during deployment**.

- Another important line in the yaml itself is:

> # Pod CIDR auto-detection on kubeadm needs access to config maps.

This confirms that the CIDR is obtained from the cluster, not from `calico.yaml`.

---

> What are these two different IPs? My Pods are getting IP addresses 20.96.205.192 and so on.

- Kubeadm supports many [Pod network add-ons](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network), Calico is one of those. Calico on the other hand is supported by many kinds of deployment, kubeadm is just one of those.
- Kubeadm `--pod-network-cidr` in your deployment is the correct way to define the pod network CIDR, this is why the range `20.96.0.0/12` is effectively used.
- `CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR` is required for other kinds of deployment that does not specify the CIDR pool reservation for pod networks.

---

**Note:**

- The range `20.96.0.0/12` is not a [Private Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) range, and it can cause problems if a client with a Public IP from that range tries to access your service.
- The [classless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) reserved IP ranges for Private Networks are:

  - 10.0.0.0/8 (16.777.216 addresses)
  - 172.16.0.0/12 (1.048.576 addresses)
  - 192.168.0.0/16 (65.536 addresses)
- You can use any subnet size inside these ranges for your POD CIDR Network, just make sure it doesn't overlaps with any subnet in your network.

**Additional References:**

- [Calico - Create Single Host Kubernetes Cluster with Kubeadm](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/quickstart#create-a-single-host-kubernetes-cluster)
- [Kubeadm Calico Installation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#tabs-pod-install-0)
- [IETF RFC1918 - Private Address Space](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918#section-3)

Comment: Is the TL;DR, Calico uses `--pod-network-cidr` by default?

Comment: that's why it's a black hole if not a private range,  client packets go in,  but they can't go out.   it is rumored my org routes some of the private ranges but I don't want to disturb the network people right now lol,  that's the reality in the wild.